# Performance issue with off-screen canvas in Firefox

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, canvas

I'm having the following problem, and I believe I must be doing something stupid, but I can't find it. (This is in Firefox 8)

I'm taking a large sprite file, making a new small canvas to hold just *one* tile of that sprite, and then using the most basic overload of `drawImage` to draw this isolated tile in hundreds of places in my "screen" canvas.

I'm doing this instead of simply using the last overload of `drawImage`, that takes only a piece of the larger sprite file. By avoiding this clipping, in Chrome, I get a performance increase of about 10%, to my surprise. However, in Firefox, frame rate drops from 300 to 17 FPS.

So, what I'm seeing essentially is that drawing "from image to canvas" is about 20 times faster than drawing "from canvas to canvas" in Firefox.

Is this correct? I haven't found any information on this particular case, but this is what I see on my tests.

Also, this the code I'm using. Am I doing anything incredibly stupid?

```
function Test5() {
    var imgSprite = $('imgSprite');
    var tileCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    tileCanvas.width = 64; tileCanvas.height = 31;
    var tileCtx = tileCanvas.getContext("2d");
    tileCtx.drawImage(imgSprite, 0, 0, 64, 31, 0, 0, 64, 31);

    //--------------------------------------
    var ctx = getContext('mainScreen');

    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';

    time(function() { // time will run this function many times and time it
        ctx.fillRect(0,0, 1200,900);
        var x=0, y=0, row = 0;
        for (var i=1; i < 1000; i++) {
            ctx.drawImage(tileCanvas, x,y); // <-- this is the line I care about
            // some simple code to calculate new x/y
        }
    }, 1000, "Test5", 'Drawing from an individual tile canvas, instead of a section of big sprite');
}
```

If, instead of

```
 ctx.drawImage(tileCanvas, x,y);
```

I do :

```
 ctx.drawImage(imgSprite, 0, 0, 64, 31, x, y, 64, 31);
```

That's 20 times faster

Am I missing something here?

---

**EDIT:** After asking this I made a little page for myself to test several different things in different platforms and see what was the best way to do things in each.

http://www.crystalgears.com/isoengine/jstests3-canvas.html

I'm sorry that code is horrifically ugly, it was a quick hack, not meant to be seen by others, or even myself in a few days.

Comment: can you show us the results and code of `time()` so we can play?

Comment: http://www.crystalgears.com/isoengine/jstests3-canvas.html  - time() is a ridiculously simple function. Check that page, it's a bunch of different ways of doing the same thing that I used to test the best way in different platforms. To reproduce this, click the 3 "Test 1" buttons. You'll notice the canvas one is 20x slower than the other 2. Sorry the code is ugly and a huge mess, i did this mostly as a quick hack, and this is actually the result of copy/pasting/merging from another quick hack. But you can test a number of interesting things with this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be sure without profiling (esp. with your particular images and maybe your particular graphics card+driver), but you may be hitting https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=705559

Certainly that bug should cause drawImage with `<canvas>` argument to be somewhat slower; though 20x slower is very surprising (hence the "may").

Comment: Oh, ok... Thank you for that response, that explains it. Hopefully they'll fix it eventually. In the meantime, I also noticed that using little images (Created with toDataURL()) is faster in Safari iPhone than using canvas, so i'm branching a bit and using canvas for Android/Chrome, and toDataURL() for Firefox/iPhone. But in case it helps the profiling / improvement of this, this may help: http://www.crystalgears.com/isoengine/jstests3-canvas.html

Comment: Oh, by the way... Not sure if this is considered a "bug", but another thing I noticed is that, if I draw outside the "canvas area" in Chrome, it's stupidly fast, whereas in Firefox it's the exact same speed as drawing inside the canvas. (You can see this by comparing the performance of Test5 and Test9 in that test page). It seems Chrome checks bounds first, and decides to not even to the blitting. It may or may not make sense to implement something like this, not sure about use cases, just noticed this huge difference in behavior.

Comment: I don't see any sort of special-case path in the Firefox code for the case when the draw is entirely outside the canvas...  I wonder whether that's something people actually do commonly.  Thanks for the testcases!